# Create custom package - and add a private repository

Tags: ppa, repository, packaging

While developing a custom, commercial application, I need to provide appropriate automatic updates.

Can I create a package that, in addition to containing my specific application, also adds it's repository to the sources list?

Is it the appropriate procedure?

Comment: I think google chrome does the same thing ,when I installed google chrome ,it automatically add it is repository to sources.list

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a common approach. I don't think it's ideal, but it certainly works.

You can drop the sources list into

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

And add the APT key from the maintainer scripts.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't optimal? Any better solutions? The app doesn't have the market penetration to be included in any existing repo..

Comment: In the future, we'd like to have `.list` files or something like that, that adds a repository to your system and installs a package. Installing a package shouldn't modify your system's APT configuration, that's not very friendly behavior.

Comment: `.list` files? Forgive my ignorance, but how would that work?

Comment: http://mariusv.wordpress.com/2007/12/02/the-maemo-extras-catalogue-and-its-dot-install-files/